# beacon-ui-elixir client error about referenceGenome

Tags: angular, user-interface, elixir, bioinformatics, beacon

Sorry Google search did not help me with this. Angular specialists, please suggest some interpretation.

So, I cloned and installed a docker container of this app:

https://github.com/ga4gh-beacon/beacon-ui-elixir

The only custom change I made in Dockerfile jdk version from the default jdk-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz which is not available anymore to jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz which should be irrelevant to the question since the error is from the client. The container got installed and started fine (actually, it's 3 containers installed with docker-compose).

The UI component loads Elixir Beacon in the browser fine as it should at http://localhost:6080. However, any attempt to search (on existing or non-existing data) results in this Angular error (browser console,  differently in Chrome and Firefox but from the same line.

Apparently it's comung from Angular:

```
/src/js/app/beacons/beacons.js:249:                    searchParams.assemblyId = angular.copy($scope.datasets[searchParams.datasetIds].referenceGenome);
```

It's in this file and I do not know Angular at all:

```
https://github.com/ga4gh-beacon/beacon-ui-elixir/blob/master/src/js/app/beacons/beacons.js
```

I can only guess that it's something is not configured to connect to the model at all.

The error looks like this:
In Chrome:

```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'referenceGenome' of undefined
>     at r.$scope.beaconSearch (app-4fd81e44d8.js:30)
>     at fn (eval at compile (app-4fd81e44d8.js:9), <anonymous>:4:432)
>     at e (app-4fd81e44d8.js:9)
>     at r.$eval (app-4fd81e44d8.js:7)
>     at r.$apply (app-4fd81e44d8.js:7)
>     at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (app-4fd81e44d8.js:9)
>     at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (app-4fd81e44d8.js:2)
>     at HTMLFormElement.r.handle (app-4fd81e44d8.js:2)
```

My note here: there's nothing in the Db that can be referred to as "referenceGenome".

In Firefox:

```
> Error: $scope.datasets[searchParams.datasetIds] is undefined
> $scope.beaconSearch@http://localhost:6080/js/app-4fd81e44d8.js:30:8614
> fn@http://localhost:6080/js/app-4fd81e44d8.js line 9 > Function:4:429
> e@http://localhost:6080/js/app-4fd81e44d8.js:9:23637
> $eval@http://localhost:6080/js/app-4fd81e44d8.js:7:24697
> $apply@http://localhost:6080/js/app-4fd81e44d8.js:7:24926
> compile/</<@http://localhost:6080/js/app-4fd81e44d8.js:9:23687
> dispatch@http://localhost:6080/js/app-4fd81e44d8.js:2:17278
> add/r.handle@http://localhost:6080/js/app-4fd81e44d8.js:2:14027
> app-4fd81e44d8.js:7:11339 e/<
> http://localhost:6080/js/app-4fd81e44d8.js:7:11339 ef/this.$get</<
> http://localhost:6080/js/app-4fd81e44d8.js:6:29944 $apply
> http://localhost:6080/js/app-4fd81e44d8.js:7:24973 compile/</<
> http://localhost:6080/js/app-4fd81e44d8.js:9:23687 dispatch
> http://localhost:6080/js/app-4fd81e44d8.js:2:17278 add/r.handle
> http://localhost:6080/js/app-4fd81e44d8.js:2:14027
```

Thanks